# how do I display text in PHP only if there is more than 1 page in a simple pagination?

Tags: php, pagination, echo, printf

This is not my code and the author has neglected to answer my queries as he put it "I didn't make the script to be played with". lol That being said, I have a simple question.  The below code creates a pagination, but only displays itself if there is more than one page to show.  I'd like to add a "Select Page" text to it, but, as with the page numbers, have it only display if there is more than one page. I played around with it, adding an echo, which works, but it displays all the time, not only if multiple pages.

Can anyone help please? I'm still a PHP newbie.  Thanks!!

```
<?php 
# variable declaration
$prev_rs_products = $lang['products_navigation_previous'];
$next_rs_products =$lang['products_navigation_next'];
$separator = " | ";
$max_links = 100;
$pages_navigation_rs_products = buildNavigation($pageNum_rs_products,$totalPages_rs_products,$prev_rs_products,$next_rs_products,$separator,$max_links,true); 

print $pages_navigation_rs_products[0]; 
?>
<?php echo 'Select Page:'; print $pages_navigation_rs_products[1]; ?> <?php print  pages_navigation_rs_products[2]; ?>
```

Comment: The logic for if it should show anything or not is contained in the buildNavigation function, not the code posted. Go look there & see if you can figure out what it does.

Comment: I didn't see anything at that link that would help me :(  So I need to look at the buildNavigation function? Does it have something to do with the "true" at the end of it?  I know very little about PHP.

Comment: You need to look at the actual code for buildNavigation, not just the line where it's called (you haven't posted that code)

Comment: I'm not even sure where that particular function is at. But with some tricky coding and messing with the language file, I managed to create a work around...